# Remove Duplicate Pages so only original exists

Tags: wordpress, duplicates

Basically I have around 4000 pages on my wordpress site and I have identified 1320 are duplicates.

I know I can go select each and every one manually and then bulk move them to the trash etc but does anyone know of a more time efficient way to do this?

Perhaps a MYSQL query to delete all the duplicates pages?

An example of the urls is as follows:

(Original)

/page/

(Duplicate)

/page-2/ and sometimes even /page-3/

There must be a way to mass delete all pages with the added -2 or -3

Thanks for any and all help.

*edit

It said there was an error with that code however I managed to come up with this...

```
DELETE a.*
FROM wp_posts AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM wp_posts
      WHERE post_type = 'page'
      AND post_status = 'publish'
      GROUP BY post_title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'page'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

This managed to get rid of around 550 of the duplicates but for some reason there are still quite a lot of duplicate pages left

I created pages depending on locations and I've just realised that I have pages such as

Berwick upon Tweed

and

Berwick-Upon-Tweed

I'd Ideally like to delete the pages with the - in the title as well

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but there is a plugin that says it can do this [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-duplicate-data/screenshots/).

Comment: Thank you for that, I saw that this morning as well and might try it out if all else fails (not before making a backup of course!)

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately...

Just me brain storming but would it not be possible to run a query to find all pages that have -2 or -3 added to the end of the url and just delete all the ones that have?